# Python Regex best delimiter to use?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse a line using re.split in python. Here is an example line I am trying to work on:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName_1
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName 1
```

I use the following code to split each line into an array, and just use the last element.

```
file_folder_names_parsed.insert(file_index, (re.split(r"\s", entry)))
print file_folder_names_parsed[file_index]

#The file/folder name is stored in the last element, lets index to that
num_elements_in_parsed_string = len(file_folder_names_parsed[file_index])
parsed_folder_names.insert(file_index, file_folder_names_parsed[file_index][num_elements_in_parsed_string-1])
```

Now the issue is that for the first two lines, it works fine and I am able to populate a list with the entries : [FolderName , FolderName_1]

But for the last element, instead of getting [FolderName 1], I only get [1]. This makes sense as there is a space character in between, which I am using as a delimiter. Unfortunately, I am unable to use \t (tab) as a regular expression delimiter for the string I have to deal with.

Can anyone suggest for the last case, how can I get [FolderName 1] instead of just getting [1] which I currently get?

Comment: You could write a pattern to match each part of the string separately, rather than try to `split` and index.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place.

Comment: *Aside*: In your code above, the expression `file_folder_names_parsed[file_index][num_elements_in_parsed_string-1]` is equivalent to `file_folder_names_parsed[file_index][-1]`. More generally, whenever you want the final element of a list, use `xxx[-1]`, not `xxx[len(xxx)-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split according to the spaces which are not followed by a number and a line end anchor,

```
>>> m = re.split(r'(?<!:\d{2} \d)\s+(?!\d+$)', 'drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName 1')
>>> m
['drwxr-xr-x', '2', 'user1', 'user1', '4096', 'Sep', '4', '14:23', 'FolderName 1']
>>> m = re.split(r'(?<!:\d{2} \d)\s+(?!\d+$)', 'drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 1 FolderName')
>>> m
['drwxr-xr-x', '2', 'user1', 'user1', '4096', 'Sep', '4', '14:23', '1 FolderName']
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fM1nM4/2)

**Pattern explanation:**

- `(?<!:\d{2} \d)\s+(?!\d+$)`

  `(?<!....)` called negative lookbehind which asserts what precedes the spaces is not which satisfies this `:\d{2} \d` pattern. `(?!\d+$)` called negative lookahead which asserts, what follows is not one or more digits and a End of the line anchor `$`

Comment: Thanks Avinash, that was helpful. But in the event that I come across a case, where I have to deal with [1 FolderName], it will only parse [FolderName] and leaves out the [1 ] which was actually part of the entire folder name. Is there any way, I can allow the regex to also hand foldernames created with spaces, but beginning with a number?

Comment: Or use `regex.split(r'(?<!:\d{2}\s+\d+)\s+(?!\d+$)', s)`

Comment: Avinash, can you tell me what does this: **<!:** do? I'm not really a regex expert, and have been reading about it : http://www.9lessons.info/2013/10/understanding-regular-expression.html, but don't quite see that character explained ...

Comment: @c0d3rz i'll explain my regex please wait for some time.

Answer (score 3):

Probably something like this?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName_1
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName 1'''
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=:\d{2})\s+(.*)(?=\n|$)', s)
['FolderName', 'FolderName_1', 'FolderName 1']
```

Regex explanation: http://regex101.com/r/fM1nM4/1

Answer (score 3):

You should match a non-empty sequence of whitespace characters, like so: `\s+`. In addition, you should specify the maximum number of splits you are willing to accept, with `re.split()`'s `maxsplit` parameter:

```
import re
lines = [
'drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName',
'drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName_1',
'drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName 1',
]

for entry in lines:
  filename = re.split(r'\s+', entry, maxsplit=8)[-1]
  print filename
```

After splitting off the first 8 items, `re.split()` returns the remainder of the line as a single item.

But, if you are just going to use whitepsace as your deliminter, you don't need `re.split()` at all. Just use the simpler `str.split()`:

```
for entry in lines:
  filename = entry.split(None, 8)[-1]
  print filename
```

Either of the samples above produce this output:

```
FolderName
FolderName_1
FolderName 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't work with `split()`, work with an actual pattern.

```py
import re

listing = """drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName_1
drwxr-xr-x   2 user1    user1        4096 Sep  4 14:23 FolderName 1
asdasd
"""

listing_pattern = r"\s+".join([
    r"^(?P<type>\S)(?P<mode>\S+)",
    r"(?P<children>\d+)",
    r"(?P<user>\S+)",
    r"(?P<group>\S+)",
    r"(?P<size>\S+)",
    r"(?P<time>.*\d:\d\d)",
    r"(?P<filename>.*)",
])

for entry in iter(listing.splitlines()):
    match = re.match(listing_pattern, entry)
    if match:
        print match.group("filename")
```

prints

```
FolderName
FolderName_1
FolderName 1
```

As @tripleee points out in the comments, you should not parse the output of `ls` in the first place. In the above the weakest chain in the link is the `<time>` group (think am/pm time representations).

---

If you are not at all interested in the columns before the filename, a shorter regex will suffice:

```py
listing_pattern = r".*?:\d\d (?P<filename>.*)"
```

Again, the assumption that the time ends in a `":"` followed by two digits is the weak spot of that approach.